# Can't pass this as parameter to a delegate

Tags: c++, pointers, delegates, this

I am using a delegate class that I got from [here](http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/C++-delegates-on-steroids/) that has worked flawlessly so far. Its usage is simple, and very readable too (scroll to the end of the linked page to see its usage)

My problem is that whenever I pass `this` as the parameter instead of the standard reference `&` I get a runtime error:

`...DELEGATE(&Foo::bar, &f) //where f is an instance of Foo`

`...DELEGATE(&Foo::bar, this) //declared in class Foo (runtime error)`

How could I go about fixing this? I have fixed problems with pointers and references before, but this error totally baffles me.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error you are getting?

Comment: There is no text; simply <program> quit unexpectedly. The debugger tells me that it is coming from a line in the `Delegate.hpp` library I am using

Comment: More specifically, the line that calls the method that the delegate is holding